# R: rgeom(n,p) when n and p is not fixed

Tags: r

Situation: Assume a bag contains 1 blue ball and 1 red ball. At each turn, a ball is chosen randomly, then returned back along with another (new) ball of the same colour (So after n turns, there will always be n+2 balls in the bag).

The probability of drawing the first red on the nth turn is 
[image]

I want to write a loop that simulates the number of turns taken until the first red ball is drawn from the bag using the rgeom(n,p) code. But since n is unknown and p changes every turn, I am confused how to modify it. I tried the following code, but it won't print anything:

```
k=0
success = 0
while(success <= 1){
   k = k + 1
   if (rgeom(n, 1/(n+1) == 1) 
      success = success + 1
}
k
```

How can I write the loop?

Answer (score 1):

If I run with a couple of small changes I got some value for k:

```
set.seed(123)
k=0
success = 0
while(success < 1){ # rather than <=1, which includes 0
k = k + 1
if (rgeom(n, 1/(n+1)) == 1) # missed closing parenthesis 
success = success + 1
}
k
```

I got `k=8`

but there are lots of warnings!!